# ubuntu often crashes after entering or exiting fullscreen mode while watching youtube videos

Tags: unity

After installing ubuntu 15.10, I found that unity often crashed after entering or exiting fullscreen mode while watching youtube videos, during that time, I can only move my mouse, but I don't know why. I have two questions regarding the problem.

1. Is there any method to find the reason why ubuntu crashes and the solution to solve the problem?
2. What can I do if unity crashes? Normally I would go to tty1 and execute `sudo pkill Xorg`, but it restarts the Xorg, which is inconvenient. Which process should I kill?